# change the color of an marked text

Tags: javascript, styles, selection

is it possible to Change the Color of an marked text? this text doesn't have an id.

i don't want to use "execCommand". I thougt i use style.color (JS). But i can use it only when i have an id, but the text don't have and shouldn't have an id.

I tried this:

```
var doc = document.getElementById("iframe_editor").contentWindow.document;  
var sel = doc.getSelection();

    if (sel != '')
    {

        sel.style.color = "red";
    }
```

But "sel" is not an object.

Comment: can you wrap the selection in <span> tags, give them a class and assign that class a color using css?

Comment: no i cannot, because  the text will be written in an iframe (like an Editor)

Comment: document.getSelection() is not available in IE. In which browser and which version are you testing this code?

Comment: you can't style a  text node....either wrap it or give up

Comment: getSelection works in ie 11  / edge fine. no. i want to know a way, how can a marked/selected text a style. the text doesn't have an "id", i have only the marked / selected text

Comment: I guess I was talking about grabbing all the text from the textarea or wherever, inserting a <span class="red"> at selection start and a </span> at selection end and then writing it back to the textarea. Although applying css styles in an iframe might be tricky. The workaround would be (shudder) inline styles